# variable substitution removing quotes

Tags: bash, loops, variable-substitution

I seem to have some difficulty getting what I want to work.  Basically, I have a series of variables that are assigned strings with some quotes and \ characters. I want to remove the quotes to embed them inside a json doc, since json hates quotes using python dump methods.

I figured it would be easy.  Just determine how to remove the characters easy and then write a simple for loop for the variable substitution, well it didn't work that way.

Here is what I want to do.

There is a variable called "MESSAGE23", it contains the following "com.centrify.tokend.cac", I want to strip out the quotes, which to me is easy, a simple `echo $opt | sed "s/\"//g"`.  When I do this from the command line:

```
$> MESSAGE23="com."apple".cacng.tokend is present"
$> MESSAGE23=`echo $MESSAGE23 | sed "s/\"//g"`
$> com.apple.cacng.tokend is present
```

This works.  I get the properly formatted string.

When I then try to throw this into a loop, all hell breaks loose.

```
for i to {1..25}; do
   MESSAGE$i=`echo $MESSAGE$i | sed "s/\"//g"`
done
```

This doesn't work (either it throws a bunch of indexes out or nothing), and I'm pretty sure I just don't know enough about `arg` or `eval` or other bash substitution variables.

But basically I want to do this for another set of variables with the same problems, where I strip out the quotes and incidentally the "\" too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.  You could make it work using `eval`, but that introduces another level of quoting you have to worry about.  Is there some reason you can't use an array?

```
MESSAGE=("this is MESSAGE[0]" "this is MESSAGE[1]")
MESSAGE[2]="I can add more, too!"
for (( i=0; i<${#MESSAGE[@]}; ++i )); do
   echo "${MESSAGE[i]}"
done
```

Otherwise you need something like this:

```
 eval 'echo "$MESSAGE'"$i"'"'
```

and it just gets worse from there.

Comment: yuck.. no, not opposed to using an array?  I have variables MESSAGE1-25, Should I push each of those onto an array and then pop each off and substitute it?  I guess I'm not sure where I should put this array?

Comment: oh.. I get it.  MESSAGE is the array and pop values onto that array

Comment: Right.  Instead of `MESSAGE1=blah1`, `MESSAGE2=blah2`, etc, you can do `MESSAGE[0]=blah1`, `MESSAGE[1]=blah2`, etc.  Or initialize the whole thing with parentheses as I did, or read it in from a file using `read -a` - it just depends on how those variables are getting set in your application.

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of preliminary problems: `MESSAGE23="com."apple".cacng.tokend is present"`  will not embed double-quotes in the variable value, use `MESSAGE23="com.\"apple\".cacng.tokend is present"` or `MESSAGE23='com."apple".cacng.tokend is present'` instead. Second, you should almost always put double-quotes around variable expansions (e.g. `echo "$MESSAGE23"`) to prevent parsing oddities.

Now, the real problems: the shell doesn't allow variable substitution on the left side of an assignment (i.e. `MESSAGE$i=something` won't work). Fortunately, it does allow this in a `declare` statement, so you can use that instead. Also, when the sees `$MESSAGE$i` it replaces it will the value of `$MESSAGE` followed by the value of `$i`; for this you need to use indirect expansion (`${!metavariable}').

```
for i in {1..25}; do
    varname="MESSAGE$i"
    declare $varname="$(echo "${!varname}" | tr -d '"')"
done
```

(Note that I also used `tr` instead of `sed`, but that's just my personal preference.)

(Also, note that @Mark Reed's suggestion of an array is really the better way to do this sort of thing.)

Comment: Thanks guys.. Learned a ton here from both of you, will experiment with both the array option and using declare. Thanks